# rendering several figures in one to get cylinder in fabric.js

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

dear colleages!

I need to get cylinder in fabric.js. It should be one shape. I try to solve th problem in that way. First of all I draw two ellipses and two lines. The code of this work you can see below the text:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
let width_changed = 4;


var eli_1 = new fabric.Ellipse({
    top: 150,
    left: 400,
   /* Try same values rx, ry => circle */
    rx: 75,
    ry: 50,
    fill: '',
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: width_changed
});

var eli_2 = new fabric.Ellipse({
    top: 350,
    left: 400,
   /* Try same values rx, ry => circle */
    rx: 75,
    ry: 50,
    fill: '',
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: width_changed
});



var line_2 = new fabric.Line([ 402, 200, 402, 400 ],{
      strokeWidth: width_changed,
      fill: 'blue',
      stroke: 'blue',
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center'
    });

var line_3 = new fabric.Line([ 552, 200, 552, 400 ],{
      strokeWidth: width_changed,
      fill: 'blue',
      stroke: 'blue',
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center'
    });

var shape_1 = new Array(eli_1,eli_2,line_2,line_3);
/*
var polyg_1 = new fabric.Polygon(shape_1[1], {
    top: 280,
    left: 290,
    fill: '',
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: 2
});
*/

canvas.add(eli_1,eli_2,line_2,line_3);
//canvas.add(polyg_1);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="630" style="border:1px dotted red"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.0/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-1fOn6VtTq3PWwfsOrk45LnYcGosJwzMHv+Xh/Jx5303FVOXzEnw0EpLv30mtjmlj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@4.6.0/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

as a result I want to get something like on figure.It should be one shape

[image]

when I try to add 4 figures in one shape:

```
var shape_1 = new Array(eli_1,eli_2,line_2,line_3);
/*
var polyg_1 = new fabric.Polygon(shape_1[1], {
    top: 280,
    left: 290,
    fill: '',
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: 2
});
```

I get an error. How should I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
let width_changed = 4;


var eli_1 = new fabric.Ellipse({
    top: 150,
    left: 400,
   /* Try same values rx, ry => circle */
    rx: 75,
    ry: 50,
    fill: '',
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: width_changed
});

var eli_2 = new fabric.Ellipse({
    top: 350,
    left: 400,
   /* Try same values rx, ry => circle */
    rx: 75,
    ry: 50,
    fill: '',
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: width_changed
});



var line_2 = new fabric.Line([ 402, 200, 402, 400 ],{
      strokeWidth: width_changed,
      fill: 'blue',
      stroke: 'blue',
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center'
    });

var line_3 = new fabric.Line([ 552, 200, 552, 400 ],{
      strokeWidth: width_changed,
      fill: 'blue',
      stroke: 'blue',
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center'
    });

var group2 = new fabric.Group([ eli_1,eli_2,line_2,line_3 ], { left: 200, top: 200 });
canvas.add(group2);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="630" style="border:1px dotted red"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.0/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-1fOn6VtTq3PWwfsOrk45LnYcGosJwzMHv+Xh/Jx5303FVOXzEnw0EpLv30mtjmlj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@4.6.0/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```